# An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''. .NET Core Web API 7.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, api, connection-string

I'm setting up a web API. My program.cs file looks like this:

```
var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 29));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GameDbContext>(
    dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
        .UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db"), serverVersion, mySqlOptions =>
            mySqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 10,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null))
        );
```

And my connection string has the following template:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Db": "Server=serverIP,port;Database=dbName;User Id=userId;Password=password;"
  }
```

The API ill listen on localhost:7272 when building and running the project in Visual Studio itself. The API will handle the requests sent to this adress.

However, when I build and publish the project and then run the executable from the folder, it listens to localhost:5000, but no requests will be handled because of this error:

```
An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''.
```

I've already added the 'EnableRetryOnFailure' as suggested by others and changed the template of the connection string multiple times but still to no avail.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

I've already added the 'EnableRetryOnFailure' as suggested by others and changed the template of the connection string multiple times but still to no avail. I also added the Pomelo package.

Comment: Sounds like when you deploy it, the connectionstring is missing.

Comment: @fredrik Yeah I think so too. When I open appsettings.json, however, the connectionstring is still there. Any ideas on how to fix it?